# how does System.Web.HttpRequest::PathInfo work?

Tags: c#, nancy, system.web

I am trying to understand the PathInfo property of System.Web.HttpRequest and how it is set.

Why would it be empty in the following example?

```
var p = new System.Web.HttpRequest("file.txt","http://file.com/files/file.txt","");
//PathInfo is always empty
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PathInfo)
```

I am trying to pipe the Elmah interface through Nancyfx by invoking the Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory::ProcessRequest(HttpContext context).

but it does not work because Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory depends on HttpRequest::PathInfo to resolve the correct IHttpHandler and PathInfo is always empty.

If someone would take the time explaining how PathInfo works I would be very grateful!

Comment: I posted an answer why it's empty, but can you explain, why you even need to create HttpRequest? Probably your intention was to use the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class?

Comment: I was trying to pipe the Elmah interface through Nancyfx by invoking the Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory::ProcessRequest(HttpContext context). but it would not work because Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory depends on HttpRequest::PathInfo to resolve the correct IHttpHandler. 

updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

The `PathInfo` property is calculated basing on `HttpContext` private variable of the `HttpRequest` class. There's no official way to set this `HttpContext` instance. That's why whenever you create the `HttpRequest` manually, the `HttpContext` is always null, therefore the `PathInfo` use empty also.

To get something different from empty string you need to use a real instance, which is created by .NET framework to you, and not to instantiate it by yourself.

Comment: ah thanks yes I understand there is some correlation there but I would really like to know the mechanics inside this black box :)

Answer (score 1):

I have just been trying to do a similar thing with Elmah.

My route was set up as follows:

```
var url = "admin/elmah.axd/{*pathInfo}";
var defaults = new RouteValueDictionary {{"pathInfo", string.Empty}};
var routeHandler = new ElmahHandler();

var route = new Route(url, defaults, routeHandler);
RouteTable.Routes.Add(route);
```

But I too found that the pathinfo is always empty, so the stylesheet and additional paths didn't work. I managed to achieve my goal using reflection to call the underlying methods in the ErrorLogFactory.

```
private object InvokeMethod(string name, params object[] args)
{
   var dynMethod = typeof(ErrorLogPageFactory).GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   return dynMethod.Invoke(null, args );
}
```

Then my handler looked like this

```
public class ElmahHandler : ErrorLogPageFactory, IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var handler = InvokeMethod("FindHandler", requestContext.RouteData.Values["pathInfo"]) as IHttpHandler;

        if (handler == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "Resource not found.");

        var num = (int)InvokeMethod("IsAuthorized", context);
        if (num != 0 && (num >= 0 || HttpRequestSecurity.IsLocal(context.Request) /*|| SecurityConfiguration.Default.AllowRemoteAccess*/))
        {
            return handler;
        }

        //new ManifestResourceHandler("RemoteAccessError.htm", "text/html").ProcessRequest(context);
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;
        response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
        response.End();

        return null;
    }
}
```

I had no need to get the ManifestResourceHandler working, so just commented it out, likewise for the allowRemoteAccess setting