# Routing Issue with my asp.net MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having hectic last couple of days due to this problem. I'm trying to pass route data to the view as a matter of navigation. However routeInfo contains no route information. i.e. routeInfo.RouteData.Values.Count = 0. I have another application with the same code which is working fine.

I'm not sure what i'm  missing here.

Any help would be really appreciated!!

```
    public ActionResult Index(int type)
    {
        UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext);
        string url = u.Action("Action", "Controller", new { type = type }, Request.Url.Scheme);
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        RouteInfo routeInfo = new RouteInfo(uri, HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
        Session["_ReturnURL"] = routeInfo.RouteData.Values;
        ViewBag.ReturnURL = Helpers.GetSessionKey("_ReturnURL");

        return View();
    }


    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Controller",
            url: "Controller/{type}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Controller", action = "Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "CBlah", action = "ABlah", id = UrlParameter.Optional, returnUrl = "~/Blah2/Blah2" }
        );

    }


public class RouteInfo
{
    public RouteData RouteData { get; private set; }

    public RouteInfo(RouteData data)
    {
        RouteData = data;
    }

    public RouteInfo(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
    {
        RouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new InternalHttpContext(uri, applicationPath));
    }

    private class InternalHttpContext : HttpContextBase
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestBase _request;

        public InternalHttpContext(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
        {
            _request = new InternalRequestContext(uri, applicationPath);
        }

        public override HttpRequestBase Request { get { return _request; } }
    }

    private class InternalRequestContext : HttpRequestBase
    {
        private readonly string _appRelativePath;
        private readonly string _pathInfo;

        public InternalRequestContext(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
        {
            _pathInfo = uri.Query;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPath) || !uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(applicationPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                _appRelativePath = uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(applicationPath.Length);
            else
                _appRelativePath = uri.AbsolutePath;
        }

        public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath { get { return String.Concat("~", _appRelativePath); } }
        public override string PathInfo { get { return _pathInfo; } }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Route.GetRouteData Definition

```
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    string virtualPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) + httpContext.Request.PathInfo;
    RouteValueDictionary values = this._parsedRoute.Match(virtualPath, this.Defaults);
    if (values == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    RouteData data = new RouteData(this, this.RouteHandler);
    if (!this.ProcessConstraints(httpContext, values, RouteDirection.IncomingRequest))
    {
        return null;
    }
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
    {
        data.Values.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
    if (this.DataTokens != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair2 in this.DataTokens)
        {
            data.DataTokens[pair2.Key] = pair2.Value;
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

The problem lies in this line:

```
string virtualPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) + httpContext.Request.PathInfo;
```

You are appending a *query string* as the `httpContext.Request.PathInfo` via:

```
_pathInfo = uri.Query;
```

I know for a fact that the Route class does not consider the query string, so appending it to the path is a mistake. There is also some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459564/181087) that backs up the fact that `PathInfo` always *should* return an empty string.

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For the URL `http://www.contoso.com/virdir/page.html/tail`, the PathInfo value is `/tail`.

So, adding a query string is making this line fail (when there is a query string) because `_parsedRoute.Match` isn't expecting one.

```
RouteValueDictionary values = this._parsedRoute.Match(virtualPath, this.Defaults);
```

My guess is that one of your applications "works" because it is not being passed a URL with a query string, and therefore matches correctly. But whatever the case, you should return an empty string from `PathInfo` in your `InternalRequestContext` class to make it work 100% of the time (unless you have crazy URLs with dots in them, then you may need to do some extra work).

Comment: Thanks!! So I changed _pathInfo = uri.Query; to _pathInfo = ""; but it didn't solve the problem. Also my URL looks like http://localhost:53404/Controller/1

Comment: The rest of the code works for me - I am getting 4 route values in RouteInfo. There must be something else in your application that is interfering with it.